# Start apache as www-data on boot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have set up a webserver using apache with SSL on my ubuntu 12.04. However, when I bootup my webserver, apache starts and runs as root. It runs and occupies port 80, I have to stop it and manually start apache using service apache2 start for it to run as www-data

```
root       887  0.0  0.3 105692  6576 ?        S    17:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

What is the best way to ensure on reboot, it runs with the user www-data

Answer (score 1):

When you want to listen on port 80, apache needs root rights as it is [privileged port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged).

Upon receiving a connection on port 80, apache will spawn a worker process with non-root priviliges to handle the socket over this connection. So you are not exposed to root-exploits if there is a bug in your web application or the apache worker process.

Comment: I am however having problems with that, apache starts and keeps running as root, it does not spawn to run as www-data. My envvars is set to run as www-data however, i have to first kill apache and start again in order for it to run as www-data

Comment: You env vars are usually ignored in upstart/systemd/init scripts. You have to set the environment variables INSIDE the init script, which is a bad idea if you are using an init script that is shipped by your distro. Re-running /etc/init.d/apache start|stop|reload will actually use your environment vars. I advise not to use env vars, but the apache configuration files to store the config.