# java.net.BindException: Permission denied when creating a ServerSocket on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, sockets

I Tried to run a Java socket in mac with eclipse but it doesn't work. I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Permission denied

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:414)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:326)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:192)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:104)
    at server.MessageServer.main(MessageServer.java:11)
```

How can i make it to run?

```
package server; //ChatServer 
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

public class MessageServer { 

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException { 
    int port = 100; 
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (port); 
    System.out.println("Server is started!"); 

    while (true) { 
        Socket client = server.accept (); 
        System.out.println ("Accepted from " + client.getInetAddress ()); 
        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler (client); 
        handler.start(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what version of jdk are you using

Comment: Without the code you are using it will be much harder.

Comment: We don't know enough to properly answer the question. What is the code? What JDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using jdk 1.6 and the code for MessageServer.java

Comment: package server;

//ChatServer

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MessageServer {
 public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
  int port = 100;
  ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (port);
  System.out.println("Server is started!");
  
  while (true) {
   Socket client = server.accept ();
   System.out.println ("Accepted from " + client.getInetAddress ());
   MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler (client);
   handler.start();
  }

 }
}

Comment: @Kevbear You can see for yourself that posting code in comments is utterly illegible, i.e. a complete waste of time. Edit it into your question.

Comment: @Kevbear: When you ask a question and somebody replies, the polite thing to do would be to accept an answer.

Answer (score 70):

You can't open a port below 1024, if you don't have root privileges and from the code you posted in your comment, you seem to be trying to open port `100` which confirms my theory.

You need to use a port which is higher than 1024, if you're running the code under a non-root user.

Comment: is it possible to run it with root privileges?

Comment: Yes, such a program must be run as root user, if the binding port is below 1024.

Answer (score 26):

[Unix-based systems declare ports < 1024](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged) as "privileged" and you need admin rights to start a server.

For testing, use a port number >= 1024.

When deploying the server in production, run it with admin rights.

Comment: is it possible to run it with root privileges?

Comment: Yes, that should make it work but it also means that the whole application now has root access. So you need to be much more careful what the code could possibly do if someone was evil.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. So I decided to use only over 1024 ports

Comment: Is this unix-based design level decision as ridiculous as Billion Dollar Mistake? If it was made based on scary assumption: what if someone was scary in deed, then how that guy got the access credentials? Otherwise: now there is a caste of exclusive ports up to 1023.

Comment: @oleksii-kyslytsyn this is was decided many years ago and it makes much sense, especially when firewalls didn't exist: lower ports are reserved to system services and a regular user can't start something like an SSH backdoor without a sysadmin permission. Probably, even Windows has such protection. The null pointer problem is widely overrated anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and my port numbers were below 1024 changing port number to above 1024 solved my problem. Ports below 1024 are called Privileged Ports and in Linux (and most UNIX flavors and UNIX-like systems), they are not allowed to be opened by any non-root user.

Answer (score 2):

Many systems declare ports that are less than 1024 as "admin rights" ports. Meaning, if you're only using this for basic testing use a higher port such as 2000. This will clear the exception that you're getting by running your current program.

```
    int port = 100; 
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (port);
```

Change that to something such as:

```
    int port = 2000; 
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (port);
```

Answer (score 0):

MyServer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MyServer
{
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    public MyServer()
    {
        try 
        {
        System.out.println("Server Started ");
        ss=new ServerSocket(4444);
        s=ss.accept();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("Client Connected");
        dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ServerChat();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }   
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        new MyServer();
    }
    public void ServerChat()throws IOException
    {

        String str;
        do
        {
        str=dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Client msg : "+str);
        dos.writeUTF("Hello "+str);
        dos.flush();
        }while(!str.equals("stop"));

    }

}
```

MyClient.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MyClient
{
    Socket s;
    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    public MyClient()
    {
    try
    {
        s=new Socket("localhost",4444);
        System.out.println(s);
        din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ClientChat();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);  
    }   
    }
    public void ClientChat() throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s1;
    do
    {
    s1=br.readLine();
    dout.writeUTF(s1);
    dout.flush();
    System.out.println("Server Msg : "+din.readUTF());
    }while(!s1.equals("stop"));
    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    new MyClient();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run Server program with root (Administrator).

- Windows: Run as Administrator the IDE/Editor.
- Ubuntu/macOS: sudo java...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and I might be replying too late, but I would like to anyways share my experience in case anyone hits the issue.

I was using port# 8000, but still unable to bind to the port from a java program. It was network filter running as part of eset endpoint security that was blocking the connection.
I added a rule in eset firewall to allow port 8000, and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat: java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed) :443

I was struggling with this error and after hours figured out that root user was not logged in and the user was restarting tomcat without sudo.

if you face this issue, try logging as root and then restart tomcat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to overcome this:

- Run the service under root (not very safe)
- Use a different port
- Use a different port and (reverse) proxy to it via an upfront web server (my preferred one is nginx)
- Proxy/forward from 80 to another port via firewall (allows for port only, web proxy has more options)
- In Linux, run your service through systemctl, [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647052/275144)