# Scala spray failing to bind to EC2 Public DNS

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, spray

I just stopped running a Scala Spray executable on an EC2 Ubuntu instance to launch a newer version of the app. When I try and run the new executable I get the following error:

ubuntu@ip-172-32-92:~/suredbits-dfs$ ./target/universal/stage/bin/suredbits-dfs 
[WARN] [08/14/2015 03:22:30.314] [NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://NflDbApiActorSystemConfig/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bind to ec2-52-116-195.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.32.92:80 failed

I have checked to make sure port 80 is open and available by running this command:

```
netstat -anp | grep 80
```

which doesn't return anything. It seems that my port is open, and Scala Spray is just failing to bind again. Here is how I am attempting to start my server in my executable:

```
package com.suredbits.dfs

/**
 * Created by chris on 8/9/15.
 */

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.github.nfldb.config.{NflDbApiActorSystemConfig, NflDbApiDbConfig}
import com.suredbits.dfs.nfl.scoring.NflPlayerScoringService
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp

object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp with NflPlayerScoringService
  with NflDbApiDbConfig with NflDbApiActorSystemConfig {

  import actorSystem._

/*  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 80) {
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete {
          <h1>Say hello to spray</h1>
        }
      }
    } ~ nflPlayerScoringServiceRoutes
  }*/

  startServer(interface = "ec2-52-116-195.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", port = 80) {
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete {
          <h1>Say hello to spray</h1>
        }
      }
    } ~ nflPlayerScoringServiceRoutes
  }
}
```

Comment: Try enabling DEBUG logging which should report the underlying error.

Comment: Try running with `sudo`.

Comment: @tedder42 this was the issue, if you want to write up a post I will award the question to you.

Comment: @ChrisStewart done- I didn't want to do a full answer until I knew if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the process with `sudo`:

```
sudo ./target/universal/stage/bin/suredbits-dfs
```

Why? [You are trying to use a privileged port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged) (a port under 1024). Only root has access to those ports. The clue that tipped me off to this was that you checked `netstat` and nothing else was on port 80.