# Spring boot security with http port 80 not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am not able to run my spring boot application with spring security configured on HTTP port 80.

Getting error.

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:978) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:628) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:247) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:190) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at com.glam.admin.GlamorousyouadminApplication.main(GlamorousyouadminApplication.java:17) [classes!/:Glam-Admin]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [glamorousyouadmin-Glam-Admin.jar:Glam-Admin]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [glamorousyouadmin-Glam-Admin.jar:Glam-Admin]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [glamorousyouadmin-Glam-Admin.jar:Glam-Admin]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [glamorousyouadmin-Glam-Admin.jar:Glam-Admin]
```

2017-05-10 21:58:20.350 ERROR 7903 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]

Comment: Which OS are you trying to start your app.? You may need Sudo access to start a process under 1024 in linux based systems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged

Comment: Using linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

On U/LINUX systems you are not allowed to open ports < 1024 as non root user.
You can run your app as root (i would not recommed this) or put something as a proxy in front of your app (e.g. Apache).

Also I suppose that you can add some iptable rules to redirect the traffic from 80 to the port of your application, but I would not go this way.

Comment: When i deploy in achape-tomcat it not allowing tomcat to startup, it is working fine on my local system using sudo.

Comment: Yes, by using sudo you actually run the process with super user (root) rights. You can not run your tomcat on ports < 1024 as not root user either.