# python socket program : Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, sockets

```
>> server.bind(('192.168.38.23',80)) 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth     
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) 
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Why is it not assigning this address?

Comment: [edit] your post and include the output of `ping 192.168.38.23`

Answer (score 0):

It's usually because you don't have permissions to do that. Usually ports below `1024` are restricted to root on Linux machines (privileged ports). For further context you can search for `privileged ports` or read questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged).

I guess it works, if you change your line to:

```
server.bind(('192.168.38.23',8080))
```