# Mac (OS Sierra) doesn't let Tomcat server to start with port 443

Tags: macos, tomcat, port, server.xml

I have Tomcat 8.5 running on my Mac OS Sierra, and whenever I configure Connector port="443" is says that port 443 is in use.

[image]

When I do

```
nmap -p 443 localhost
```

in terminal it returns:

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https
```

and

```
lsof -i:443
```

returns

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    716 gatin  109u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1cf4d19b      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52071->151.101.1.69:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    716 gatin  121u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1a19c19b      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52097->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    716 gatin  141u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1dc35fab      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52076->a104-125-233-92.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    716 gatin  151u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1fb95a93      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52079->104.16.111.18:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    716 gatin  183u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1b866fab      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52151->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    716 gatin  189u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e19fbc6b3      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52153->151.101.1.69:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    716 gatin  201u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1cd40a93      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52200->sea15s11-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    716 gatin  233u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1cf806b3      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:50867->sea15s12-in-f10.1e100.net:https (CLOSED)
Google    716 gatin  244u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e19fbbdbb      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:52195->151.101.193.69:https (ESTABLISHED)
Opera     849 gatin   65u  IPv4 0xff33fb7e1b865dbb      0t0  TCP 192.168.3.29:50857->a29-04-08.lb.opera.technology:https (CLOSED)
```

I was trying to open 443 port by following this guide: https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mac-osx-open-port/ , but it did not help.

Comment: Macos is appropriately preventing you from binding to a privileged port because you shouldn't be doing that. Use an un-privileged port instead.

Comment: what do you mean by privileged / un-privileged ports?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged

Comment: hi @ChristopherSchultz is not there anyway to run under 443?

Comment: There are several ways. Buy you aren't using MacOS as a server, are you?