# How can I allow node to listen to ports below 1024 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: node.js, server, port, listen

I can use any `PORT` above 1023 with `server.listen(PORT)` in an nvm-installed node. How can I use system ports (e.g. below 1024) with a non-privileged user?

On our Ubuntu 16.04 servers I used to do this:

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip `readlink -f \`which node\``
```

However, we've upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and it doesn't seem to work anymore. I'm seeing the following error:

```
Error listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:925
```

This happens with all ports below 1024, so it's not just a one-off case of port being already in use.

Why wouldn't this work (anymore)? I must be missing something, or things have changed since Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged

Comment: @AbhishekMani I know this. It's not what I am asking. Note how `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Not to be a negative Norton, but these are reserved system ports. They are blocked for a reason. What is it that you need to do that actually requires a system port?

Comment: @unflores I don't want to seem ungrateful for you trying to think with me, but discussing rationale will steer us away from the question. It is, for all intents and purposes, irrelevant.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I have he same issue... everything fine in 16.04 and no longer working in 18.04

Comment: @AdiRoiban I found a solution (rather workaround) and posted it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the partition from which the executable is started is not mounted with `nosuid`.

`getcap` will not help with the troubleshooting, as it will show the attributes as set on the filesystem and not the actual capabilities available at run time.

You can check the run-time capabilities in `/proc/PID/status`.

They should look like

```
CapPrm: 0000000000000400
CapEff: 0000000000000400
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
```

On my `nosuid` partition, they were like this.

```
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
```

Hope it helps.
I was only able to find this out after consulting with a friend :)

Comment: Aren't runtime capabilities supposed to be mutable by root using `setcap`?

Comment: I think you are correct. `nvm` was installed with `node` in my home rather than system root. Encrypted homes are `nosuid`. I've accepted your answer, and posted a workaround as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

@AdiRoiban's answer might be correct about why `setcap` doesn't work. Check the filesystem that `node` is installed on. In case of `nvm`, `node` might be installed in your home directory. You home directory might be encrypted. And your encrypted home might be mounted as `nosuid`.

This is the workaround I ended up using.

---

First, install `authbind`. Then create the ports you want to be able to access as empty files in `/etc/authbind/byport/`. Give them read permissions for your user or group. For testing purposes, you can go all in with user `root:root` and permission `777`.

Next, start your node application like this:

```
authbind node index.js
```

If the application spawns a `node` process that needs access (e.g. `nodemon`) you need to give the process permission to give the child process permission, using the `--deep` command line switch.

E.g.:

```
authbind --deep nodemon --inspect index.js
```