# "Invalid state parameter passed in callback URL" error implementing Google OAuth2 in an API REST (PHP & Symfony)

Tags: php, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am developing a REST API with PHP 8.2, Symfony 6.4 and API Platform. I am finishing implementing OAuth with Google using the bundle **KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle** but I am getting the error that the title says. I have seen this problem in other threads but in my case and since it is an API, I do not have a front-end to redirect yet, but I don't know if that is really the problem.

I have divided my implementation into 3 classes: Client > Service > Controller. Below I leave the code and my configuration. (I will skip the class imports to not make it so long).

**CLIENT**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Google;

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;

class GoogleClient
{
    private Google $client;

    public function __construct(
        string $clientId,
        string $clientSecret)
    {
        $this->client = new Google([
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'redirectUri' => 'http://localhost:250/api/v1/users/google/oauth',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @throws IdentityProviderException
     */
    public function getAccessToken(string $grant = 'authorization_code', array $options = []): AccessToken
    {
        return $this->client->getAccessToken($grant, $options);
    }

    public function getUserInfo(AccessToken $accessToken): array
    {
        $resourceOwner = $this->client->getResourceOwner($accessToken);

        return $resourceOwner->toArray();
    }
}
```

**SERVICE**

The "authorize" function is the function that is responsible for checking if a user exists in the database. If it does not exist, call to the function "createUser" and creates it, returns a JSON token with which to authenticate created with **Lexik JWTAuthenticationBundle** bundle. As I said before, I still no have a front-end to test the routes, so I am testing it using the URL provided by Google:

[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=(MY ID).apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:250/api/v1/users/google/oauth&scope=email%20profile&access_type=offline&prompt=consent](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=(MY%20ID).apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:250/api/v1/users/google/oauth&scope=email%20profile&access_type=offline&prompt=consent)

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\Google;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Exception\User\UserNotFoundException;
use App\Http\Google\GoogleClient;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Service\Password\EncoderService;
use Doctrine\ORM\Exception\ORMException;
use Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException;
use Exception;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\OAuth2Authenticator;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\SelfValidatingPassport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class GoogleService extends OAuth2Authenticator implements AuthenticationEntrypointInterface
{
    private ClientRegistry $clientRegistry;
    private EncoderService $encoderService;
    private GoogleClient $googleClient;
    private JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTTokenManager;
    private UserRepository $userRepository;


    public function __construct(
        ClientRegistry $clientRegistry,
        EncoderService $encoderService,
        GoogleClient $googleClient,
        JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTTokenManager,
        UserRepository $userRepository
        )
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->encoderService = $encoderService;
        $this->googleClient = $googleClient;
        $this->JWTTokenManager = $JWTTokenManager;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * CUSTOM FUNCTIONS
     */

    /**
     * @throws OptimisticLockException
     * @throws ORMException
     */
    public function authorize(string $code): string
    {
        try {
            $accessToken = $this->googleClient->getAccessToken('authorization_code', ['code' => $code]);
            $userProfile = $this->googleClient->getUserInfo($accessToken);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException(sprintf('Google error. Message: %s', $exception->getMessage()));
        }

        $googleEmail = $userProfile['email'] ?? null;
        $googleName = $userProfile['name'] ?? null;

        if (null === $googleEmail) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Google account without E-Mail.');
        }

        try {
            $user = $this->userRepository->findOneByEmailOrFail($googleEmail);
        } catch (UserNotFoundException) {
            $user = $this->createUser($googleName, $googleEmail);
        }

        return $this->JWTTokenManager->create($user);
    }

    /**
     * @throws OptimisticLockException
     * @throws ORMException
     */
    private function createUser(string $name, string $email): User
    {
        $user = new User($name, $email);

        $user->setPassword($this->encoderService->generateEncodedPassword($user, \sha1(\uniqid())));
        $user->setActive(true);
        $user->setToken(null);

        $this->userRepository->save($user);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * OAUTH2AUTHENTICATOR FUNCTIONS
     */

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'google_oauth';
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('google');
        $accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function() use ($accessToken, $client) {
                return $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);
            })
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response(
            $message, Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        );
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        return new Response(
            'JWT required', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Action\Google;

use App\Service\Google\GoogleService;
use Doctrine\ORM\Exception\ORMException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;

#[AsController]
class Authorization
{
    private GoogleService $googleService;

    public function __construct(GoogleService $googleService)
    {
        $this->googleService = $googleService;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $code = $request->query->get('code');

        if (!$code) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                ['error' => 'Authorization code not provided.'],
                Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN
            );
        }

        try {
            $token = $this->googleService->authorize($code);

            return new JsonResponse(
                ['token' => $token]
            );
        } catch (ORMException $exception) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                ['error' => $exception->getMessage()],
                Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**API ENDPOINT**

```
google_oauth:
   class: ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get
   controller: App\Controller\Action\Google\Authorization
   deserialize: false
   method: GET
   uriTemplate: /users/google/oauth

   openapi:
      summary: OAuth with Google.
      requestBody:
         content:
            application/json:
               schema:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    code:
                      type: string
                      required: true

         responses:
            200:
               description: OK
               content:
                  application/json:
                     schema:
                        type: object
                        properties:
                           token:
                              type: string
```

**SECURITY.YAML**

As specified in documentation.

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    google_oauth:
        pattern: ^/api/v1/users/google/oauth
        methods: [GET]
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Service\Google\GoogleService
```

**KNPU_OAUTH2_CLIENT.YAML**

```
knpu_oauth2_client:
    clients:
        google:
            type: google
            client_id: '%env(OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)%'
            redirect_route: google_oauth
            redirect_params: {}
```

**GOOGLE CLOUD CONSOLE ROUTES**

- Authorized JavaScript Sources: http://localhost:250
- Authorized redirect URI's: http://localhost:250/api/v1/users/google/oauth

The truth is that I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I don't know where to look anymore. This is the first time I have implemented a system like this and I don't see where the error could be.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to check the functionality with the URL that Google provides for debugging: [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=(MY ID).apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:250/api/v1/users/google/oauth&scope=email%20profile&access_type=offline&prompt=consent](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=(MY%20ID).apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:250/api/v1/users/google/oauth&scope=email%20profile&access_type=offline&prompt=consent)

I have changed and checked the routes in the Google Cloud Console. I have also tried doing "var_dump" at different points in the code but it does not return anything.

I have also tried testing in different browsers (Google Chrome, Opera and Firefox), but I get the same result in all of them.

Comment: _"so I am testing it using the URL provided by Google"_ - the URL _generated_ by your bundle you mean, yes? (Not something you cobbled together yourself, manually.) I don't see any `state` parameter in that URL.

Comment: (Likely not related to your problem, but - why are you running this on `localhost:250`? Ports below 1024 are "privileged", and should not be used for your own custom applications. https://stackoverflow.com/q/10182798/1427878)

Comment: @CBroe This ports are the ports I am using in my Docker Nginx. This is my container but I had not problem with the rest of the API and endpoint.

```
  open-rally-edge-nginx:
    container_name: open-rally-edge-nginx
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      args:
        UID: $U_ID
    ports:
      - 250:80
    volumes:
      - ./public:/appdata/www/public
    depends_on:
      - open-rally-edge-core
    networks:
      - open-rally-edge-network
```

Comment: @CBroe And yes, the URL is the one generated by my bundle.

Comment: @CBroe Probably the problem is that I am not testing it properly. I have been using Postman for the rest of my endpoints but I am not sure how to do it with OAuth2. The URL you asked for before, I found it in an old article in order to get the authorization screen.

Comment: It sounds like it is complaining about the `state` parameter, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#request-parameter-state, but I am not even seeing that as part of the URLs you mentioned.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it looks like this is the problem. I am going to research the state parameter and I am going to create a little front-end and see if the problem comes from the back-end or not. Thanks for your time.